# Does Paypal-PHP-SDK V2 support Webhooks?

Tags: php, paypal, webhooks

I am trying to implement Paypal's PHP sdk to create a subscription processor on my website. On their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/#) they have a link to their Checkout V2 github link for PHP. On their side navigation menu, they have a link to Webhook implementation, but this just links to the deprecated version 1 of their
documentation.

I cannot seem to find any information on how to setup a webhook to consume subscription creations, cancellations, successful payment notifications etc for their V2 code.

Are webhooks still supported in V2?

Answer (score -1):

The PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated. As noted [in the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/deprecated-rest-sdks/):

> These `/v1/payments` and general-purpose REST SDKs are deprecated. See [our current SDK offerings](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/), which include the `/v2/checkout` and Payouts use cases. For other APIs, use [direct integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/).

Webhooks is one of those other APIs, for which you should use direct integration.

This means no SDK.